# Aikau Select not getting filled with options

Tags: dojo, html-select, alfresco-share, aikau

Here is my widget configuration :

```
id: "MY_CUSTOM_SELECT",
    name: "resources/saved-research-share/js/faceted-search/SavedResearchList",
    config: {
        fieldId: "MY_CUSTOM_SELECT_LIST",
        name: "customWidget",
        label: msg.get("faceted.search.menu.select.saved.research.label"),
        scopeFormControls: false,
        align: "left",
        optionsConfig: {
            publishTopic: "ALF_GET_FORM_CONTROL_OPTIONS",
            publishPayload: {
                url: url.context + "/proxy/alfresco/addon/savedResearch",
                itemsAttribute: "entries",
                labelAttribute: "id",
                valueAttribute: "value"
            },
            updateTopics: [
                { topic:"SAVED_RESEARCH_DELETED", global: true },
                { topic:"SAVED_RESEARCH_CREATED", global: true }
            ],
            publishGlobal: true
        }
    }
```

The custom widget is just a small extension of the basic select, adding a subscription on the "valuechangeOf" event and using navigation service to reach the value behind the option.

[My problem is that I can't manage to display something in share, as you can see:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRbaE.png)

The HTTP call is effectivly made and I'm getting a 200OK with the following JSON content :

```
{
    "entries" :
    [
        {
            "id" : "my research",
            "value" : "http://localhost:8081/share/page/dp/ws/faceted-search#searchTerm=project%20test&scope=repo&sortField=null"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas why the Select component won't be using the given configuration ?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT : I'm using Share 5.2.3 ent which integrate aikau-1.0.101.10